# Elements Of the periodic table

Tags: nuclear-physics, elements

Why even-numbered elements, with their even proton numbers are more abundant than odd-numbered elements ?

Comment: I disagree with your premise. The odd-numbered element hydrogen accounts for about [74% of the mass in the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements), making it more abundant than all the even-numbered elements put together.

Comment: Unclear. What is your definition of "more abundant"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are elements with even atomic number more abundant?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/340447/)